# Javascript - Convert dom element reference to node

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

in jQuery you can do something like this:

```
var domElement = document.getElementById("myId");
var tmp = jQuery(domElement);
```

upon which you can get the node

```
var node = tmp[0];
```

I would like to know how something like this can be done in native javascript.

Regards

Comment: Honest question: What did you think `domElement` was and what the difference between `domElement` and `node` was? Assuming you knew that `document.getElementById` is the DOM API, not jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

Your **domElement** variable is the **node** of the DOM tree. That tmp variable wraps it into a jQuery object and the [0] indexer gets the DOM element back. So the native JavaScript is the first line of your code.

Answer (score 0):

```
var domElement = document.getElementById("myId");
```

here you get the `DOMelement` or `DOM Node`

```
var tmp = jQuery(domElement);
```

here you get the `DOM element` wrapped in `jQuery`. So its like `DOM Element` wrapped in jQuery so that `jQuery` functions can applied to it.

In effect there is no difference between `DOM element` and `node` in native javascript.

Answer (score 0):

In short `var node = document.getElementById("myId");` is exactly what you want to do in your code with naive javascript.

To explain, in `var domElement = document.getElementById("myId");`

you are referencing the node with `myId` to `domElement`, then with `var tmp = jQuery(domElement);`, you get that dom element as jquery object.

`var node = tmp[0];` selects first child of `tmp` as dom element which in conclusion equals to
`document.getElementById("myId")`

Comment: FYI - `document.getElementById("myId")[0]` will return undefined, since getElementById returns the node. Something like `document.getElementsByTagName('div')[0]` does work tho.